# Javascript (Ember) I18N for a block, not just a string

Tags: ember.js, internationalization, ember-i18n

We're using [ember-i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n) to do i18n in our Ember app, and so far it's been fine. We've got a bunch of keys for strings like "Cancel" and "Save" and "Please don't do that", but I'm not sure if string-based i18n is the right way to approach the section I hit today, which is basically a warning (I'm inventing this text, but the sentiment is the same):

> Stop! What you're about to do cannot be undone. If you click the next button, you accept responsibility for:
>
> - Three small children
> - The Greek sovereign debt crisis
> - Windows 98
>
> If you agree, click "I Agree" to continue.

Should I just put a bunch of keys in the language file for that block? One key for the whole shebang, HTML and all? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi @pjmorse i would suggest you to use a **bunch of keys**  for two reasons.

1. Here both html tag and text are need to be combined as a value for the key you needed.

eg:

```
Stop! What you're about to do cannot be undone. If you click the next button, you accept responsibility for: <br>
<ul>
<li>
Three small children<li>
<li>The Greek sovereign debt crisis<li>
<li>Windows 98<li>
</ul>
```

which would be bad practice to my knowledge.
Also,

2 . what if you want to change the `<ul> to <ol>`

you need to change in all your language files. so better use bunch of keys and seperate the html design from internationalization.

happy coding.